# Duty of savedInstanceState in Android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [onSaveInstanceState () and onRestoreInstanceState ()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096169/onsaveinstancestate-and-onrestoreinstancestate)

Please Help me by providing proper explination for following Questions on SavedInstanceState in Android.

1. Why SavedInstanceState is Usefull.?
2. What is the main purpose of SavedInstanceState.?
3. How and where it will be usefull .?
4. What are the alternatives to SavedInstanceState.?
5. what state it will save.?

Thanks in advance..........

Comment: Just check [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096169/onsaveinstancestate-and-onrestoreinstancestate], [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096169/onsaveinstancestate-and-onrestoreinstancestate], [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954689/android-onsaveinstancestate-usage]

Comment: you're actually asking 5 questions in one. are you sure you have searched properly? Android documentation is pretty good on almost all of the topics